# Get split message

Tags: java

I have a question on split. I have the following codes:

```
String [] text = serverMsg.split(",");
```

How do I get the message which has been splited (lets say I have 3 sentences splited by ",")

How do I set each of them on different textfield (eg. text1, text2, text3)?

Comment: What do you mean by "textfield"?

Comment: is the same as textbox in c#

Comment: @MarounMaroun JTextfield I guess.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea It doesn't have to be Swing, maybe `java.awt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the textfields saved in some array, say:

```
TextField[] fields = ...;
```

Then iterate on the created array and [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) the text:

```
for(int i = 0;i < text.length; i++) {
    fields[i].setText(text[i]);
}
```

Note that here I assume same length of `text` and `fields`.